# Can anyone find out why i am still getting this error, "Error creating bean with name 'dataSource'"

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I have similar spring web projects setups and they are working fine. But then I switched to maven, and for some reason, I keep on getting this error, although I don't see anything wrong.

Initially I was using properties file for config, but after error I set property inside `applicationContext`, Still I get the error.

File: ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <!--    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
              p:location="/WEB-INF/database.properties"/>   -->

    <!--<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>-->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anidb" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>

       <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
```

This is how my xml looks like.
File: web.xml

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
```

File: POM.xml
I'm using only these dependencies as of right now.

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

This is the error on my console:

```
    Severe:   Exception while loading the app
    Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /AnneSite
    Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
```

I have checked for syntax, url and everything else, tried clearing the dependencies, cleaned, built and recompiled multiple times. Not sure what I'm missing here.. May be I need to compile mvn from cmd? It would be a really big help if anyone have some suggestions.

Comment: You are missing mysql driver in dependencies

Comment: @user7294900 oh man.. thank u for pointing that out, I figured the class would be invoked from jdbc dependency